# CSS :active не срабатывает при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: html, css

Не хочет нажиматься кнопка "Связаться" (анимироваться (:active)). Проблема скорее всего с использованием nav и div, но я в упор не пойму, где косяк. Заранее благодарен за понимание и подсказку.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'K2D', sans-serif;
}

nav li {
  border: 2px solid #204156; 
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 5px;  
}

.btn {
  background: #51d132;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 60px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #1e5111;
  transition: .3s;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3daa22;
}

.btn:active {
  top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <title>Понятное дело</title>
  <link ref="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=K2D" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <h4>Заголовок</h4>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Обо мне</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Галерея</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>  
  </nav>
  <h1>Текст!</h1>
  <p>Еще текст.</p>
  <div class="btn"><a>Связаться</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`top, right, bottom, left` работает только если у елемента заданно свойство `position`.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'K2D', sans-serif;
}

nav li {
  border: 2px solid #204156; 
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 5px;  
}

.btn {
  background: #51d132;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 60px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #1e5111;
  transition: .3s;
  /**/
  position: relative;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3daa22;
}

.btn:active {
  top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <title>Понятное дело</title>
  <link ref="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=K2D" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <h4>Заголовок</h4>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Обо мне</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Галерея</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>  
  </nav>
  <h1>Текст!</h1>
  <p>Еще текст.</p>
  <div class="btn"><a>Связаться</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```